# How to change avatar of the comment author using comment ID?

Tags: comments, avatar, gravatar

One visitor commented on one of my post as a guest. Now, i want to change avatar of this comment using comment ID. Comment ID of the comment is 1092. How can i change avatar of the comment using comment id?

Actually i want to change avatar for couple of comments.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pre_get_avatar`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_avatar/) filter to manipulate comment avatar html and stop WP from getting a default avatar for the comment.

> *Passing a non-null value will effectively short-circuit get_avatar(),
> passing the value through the ‘get_avatar’ filter and returning early.*

E.g.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_avatar', 'my_filter_pre_get_avatar', 10, 3 );
function my_filter_pre_get_avatar( $avatar_html, $id_or_email, $args ) {
    if ( is_a( $id_or_email, 'WP_Comment' ) ) {
        // Add more cases with elseif or use a switch statement here
        if ( '1092' === $id_or_email->comment_ID ) {
            // set avatar to whatever html you want
            $avatar_html = '<img class="avatar" src="" alt="Custom avatar">';
        }
    }
    return $avatar_html;
}
```

Use this in your theme's `functions.php` file or in a [custom plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/).

Comment: Thank you sir, exactly what I was looking for!